# JQuery toggle box - weird text break in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, css, html, text

I'm trying to add a toggle box via Jquery to a page, where if a user clicks a button, then a box centered in the screen will slide open and present some info. I have it working fine in Chrome and Safari:

[image]
 but Firefox and IE is having an odd break in the first line of text:

[image]

The error only happens to the first line, so if I remove the first line (h7), the same break happens to the next line (p), and so on... The only thing that fixes this is adding "overflow; hidden;" to the red box div, but doing so also moves the box to the lower right side of the page instead of centering it, despite my "margin: 0 auto;"... I also tried "left: 50%, right: 50%" but to no avail. However, if I reduce my browser width to 1480px to less, the div magically centers. What gives?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Please and thank you!

Comment: try making a fiddle with it! :)

Comment: Here's what I have... http://jsfiddle.net/A7f2p/68/

Comment: IE is working fine here, but firefox is having some problems, which is uncommon to MS be less problematic than MOZ. Try a css reset!